# Help for writing a trigger

Tags: trigger, code

I need to write a trigger :-
A task should be assigned to an account on account creation if the reporting country of an account owner is in the United States. 
I have written the code partially, but I'm getting stuck on the task part. The reporting country part is a tricky one for me to handle...

```
trigger CreateTask on Account (before insert)
 {
    Map <ID, User> userMap = new Map<ID, User>();
    List<Account>accountInfoList = new List<Account>();
    List<Account>accountList = new List<Account>();
    Set<id>OwnerIDSet = new set<id>();

    for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
    {
        OwnerIDSet.add(acc.OwnerID); 
        accountInfoList.add(acc);
    }

    userMap = new Map<ID,User>([Select ID, Reporting_Country__c, Email, UserName 
            from User where ID in :OwnerIDSet]);

    if (accountInfoList.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Account acc : accountInfoList) 
        {
            if (acc.SDO_Billing_Country_Name__c == userMap.get(acc.OwnerID).Reporting_Country__c)
            {
                accountList.add(acc);
            }
        }
    }

    System.debug('accountList - ' + accountList.size());
    List<Task> InsertTask = new List <Task>();

    if (accountList.size()>0)
    {
        for(Account acc:accountList) 
        {
            Task t = new Task();
            t.OwnerID = acc.OwnerID;
            t.subject= 'Task creation';
            t.status = 'in progress';
            t.priority  = 'high';
            // InsertTask.add
```

Answer (score 4):

I would move it to an AfterInsert trigger, and then assign the task WhatId to the relevant Account Id. Try this:

```
trigger CreateTask on Account (after insert)
{
    Map <ID, User> userMap = new Map<ID, User>();
    List<Account>accountInfoList = New List<Account>();
    List<Account>accountList = New List<Account>();
    Set<id>OwnerIDSet = new set<id>();

    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {

        OwnerIDSet.add(acc.OwnerID); 
        accountInfoList.add(acc);
    }

    userMap = new Map<ID,User>([
        SELECT 
            ID, 
            Reporting_Country__c, 
            Email, 
            UserName 
        FROM 
            User 
        WHERE 
            Id IN : OwnerIDSet
    ]);

    if (accountInfoList.size()>0) {

        for (Account acc : accountInfoList) {

            if (acc.SDO_Billing_Country_Name__c == userMap.get(acc.OwnerID).Reporting_Country__c) {

                accountList.add(acc);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Task> InsertTask = new List <Task>();

    if (accountList.size()>0) {

        for (Account acc : accountList) {

        Task t = new Task();
        t.OwnerID = acc.OwnerID;
        t.subject= 'Task creation';
        t.status = 'in progress';
        t.priority  = 'high';
        t.WhatId = acc.Id

        InsertTask.add(t);
    }

    if (!InsertTask.isEmpty()) {

        insert InsertTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DavinC's answer identifies the key point that you need the Account Id to be able to do this and that is not available in a "before insert" trigger but is in an "after insert" trigger.

Your question says:

> if the reporting country of account owner is united states

(which isn't consistent with the code you posted) but here is how I would write that trigger:

```
trigger CreateTask on Account (after insert) {
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        ownerIds.add(a.OwnerId); 
    }
    Map <Id, User> users = new Map<Id,User>([
            select Id
            from User 
            where Id in :ownerIds
            and Reporting_Country__c in ('United States', 'USA')
            ]);
    List<Task> inserts = new List<Task>();
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        if (users.containsKey(a.OwnerId)) {
            inserts.add(new Task(
                    WhatId = a.Id,
                    OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
                    Subject = 'Task creation',
                    Status = 'In Progress',
                    Priority = 'High'
                    ));
        }
    }
    insert inserts;
}
```